# Cocos2d x How to Sequence actions on different CCNods in the same time?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I need to run a Sequence of actions on different CCNods at the same time. Do I need to run 2 CCSequence::create ?

I need them to start at the same time and if I execute 2 CCSequence::create one after the other, the nods will not run the actions at the same time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node1->runAction(CCSequence::create(...));
node2->runAction(CCSequence::create(...));
```

This will run action at the same time. And also it is important to create CCSequence for each node.